# How to use fast-json-patch in Angular 2 applications?

Tags: json, angular, json-patch

I want to use the "fast-json-patch" library (https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/JSON-Patch) in an Angular 2 application.

I have tried adding:

`'fast-json-patch': 'vendor/fast-json-patch/dist/json-patch-duplex.min.js'`

in the `system-config.ts` file under the `map` but it doesn't work when importing `fast-json-patch`

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1) Install the package

```
npm install fast-json-patch --save
```

2) In the component, where you want to use ist, import the functions you need:

```
import { compare } from 'fast-json-patch';
```

3) To create a Patch compare the old object with the new object:

```
const patch = compare(oldObj, modifiedObj);
```

4) Print out the result:

```
console.log(patch);

0:{op: "replace", path: "/firmendetails/registergericht", value: "Darmstadt xx"}
1:{op: "remove", path: "/firmendetails/handelsname"}
2:{op: "remove", path: "/firmendetails/firma"}
3:{op: "remove", path: "/firmendetails/rechtsform"}
```